# document.getElementsByClassName() for Multiple classes not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I stuck in document.getElementsByClassName() during I optimize my company's codes.

**Here is the question:**

There are two kinds of pages I am working on:

**The first page has:**

```
<div class="leaderboardad">...</div>
```

**The second page has:**

```
<div class="leaderboard above_header">...</div>
```

We can see that the only differences is the classname, but when I want to write a js files to use document.getElementsByClassName() to detect these two div, something happen:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('leaderboard above_header')){
   console.log("2 classes");
}else if(document.getElementsByClassName('leaderboardad')){
  console.log("1 class");
}
```

**This code works fine for second page, I always get the "2 classes" in console for first page.**

Then when I change the code to

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('leaderboardad')){
   console.log("1 class");
}else if(document.getElementsByClassName('leaderboard above_header')){
  console.log("2 classes");
}
```

**This code works fine for the first page, but I always get "1 class" in console on second page.**

Suppose we can not change the classname in the pages, what can I do for this situation?

Comment: use document.queryselectorAll()

Comment: Actually my answer isn't too useful - whilst it's true that `getElementsByClassName` will always be truthy, hence fall into the first `if` statement, it's probably not going to solve your actual problem, which looks like it could be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What actual issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your help. In the pages I am working on, some have "leaderboard" class, some have "leaderboard above_header".  I want to detect these two kinds of page with js code, and I can't make changes on the html code. I got some clues in your code, big help.

Comment: ok - edited my answer to be more along the lines of what I think your'e after then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

That means that when used in an `if` statement, it will always be "truthy".  You need to check the length of the array-like object to see how many elements were returned:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('leaderboard above_header').length > 0){
    //found at least one element with both classes
    console.log("2 classes");
} else if(document.getElementsByClassName('leaderboardad').length > 0){
    //found at least one element with the single class
    console.log("1 class");
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, this is exactly the answer I find from your previous answer.